# Linking pages within tabs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a page with multiple tabs. I am trying to link to another tab from within a tab. Upon clicking the link should jump to another tab and then to a certain paragraph within that tab. This might be simple but becuase I do not have much background, I am looking for some help.

My code so far:

On the main tab when the link initiates:

```html
<div class = "class 2">
<div class = "class 3">
<a href="#secondtab" id="abc"> go to second tab </a>
</div>
</div>
```

On the second tab where the link should jump to:

```html
<p id="abc"> <span class="class 1"> jump here </span><br/><span> text text </span></p>
```

With this code I am able to jump to the second tab but it does not scroll down to the elemet id "abc".

Comment: You would need to show the full example of how these tabs works before we can jump from one to another

Comment: IDs must be unique. Two elements on a page with the same ID may cause problems. See [ID @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Comment: Thank you showdev. I have made sure that the IDs are unique in the page. The id "abc" used here twice is the same id being referenced.

Comment: Thank you Huangism. I am working on a certain block in a CMS and this is the only piece I have. Will try to see if I can include more.

Comment: Oh a CMS... if this kind of functionality is not build into the tabs you have then you could try using js to do this but seeing how you are using a CMS, not sure what the limitation are. You would need to 1 - open the other tabs first and 2 - scroll to the ID but again CMS

Comment: [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

Comment: Yes that is what I am dealing with. I am able to go to the second tab but it does not scroll down to my element.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.